# Scapy is not Capturing any packets

Tags: python-2.7, scapy, sniffing

I am trying the following command in the python interpreter but it is not capturing any packet.

```
a = sniff(prn = prnp0f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should try add callback in sniff

```
sniff(iface == "mon0", prn == PacketHandler())
```

Where PacketHandler YOUR callback